# Узнать находится ли курсор в ВИДИМОЙ части окна

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть главное окно, на этом главном окне расположен некий визуальный компонент. 
Используя SetCapture в этот визуальный компонент всегда приходят сообщения от мышки.То есть даже если окно не в фокусе и по верх него есть другое окно.

Часть элемента видна часть загорожена другим окном. Сейчас сообщения приходят всегда, не важно курсор в видимой части или в загороженной.

И я бы хотел узнать по положению курсора и hwnd элемента находится ли курсор в видимой части окна. Чтобы игнорировать сообщения когда курсор движется по невидимой части.

Делал ли кто-нибудь что-то подобное?

Answer (score 1):

[`SetCapture`](http://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcapture) - предназначена для захвата управления мышью. При "захвате" наблюдается такое поведения: события поступают в обработчик, даже если мышь находится вне зоны действия окна. В default-обработчике событий - захват происходит автоматически.  Для отключения такого поведения - используйте `ReleaseCapture()`, в большинстве случае вызов `ReleaseCapture()` ставят в click-событие, там где нежелательно такое поведение. Узнать состояние можно `GetCapture()`. Вызов `ReleaseCapture()` - не отменяет посыл окну сообщений `WM_MOUSEMOVE` и т п в случае когда событие действительно относится к даному окну (наоборот мышь не перехватывает в даном случае другое окно).

По координатам мыши - всегда можно узнать хандл окна, вызвав [`WindowFromPoint`](http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-windowfrompoint).